# Tomcat valve rewrite not working

Tags: tomcat, mod-rewrite, tomcat-valve

I want to direct any link other than a static resource (e.g. js, images, etc.) to my index.html. I have made the following changes.

I added a `context.xml` in `app.war/META-INF` directory that contains:

```
<Context>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" /> 
</Context>
```

I also have `rewrite.config` in `app.war/WEB-INF` directory that contains:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|img|js|partials|rest|favicon).*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```

However, with the above settings, what happens is that all of my js and css files show `index.html` contents (in browser console). Could you please suggest what would be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final rule re-writes everything to `/index.html`:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```

If you think the above rules will match first, you are right, except that a request to a file e.g. `/styles.css` won't match the expression you have for the static artifacts:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|img|js|partials|rest|favicon).*$
```

The problem is that you are requiring the `css` portion of the request URI to have at least one character after it. A request to `/css/style.css` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't fully get the problem that you mention. My css and js files are present as such: `/myapp/project/css/project-123.css` `/myapp/project/js/project-123.js` However, these are showing index.html content.

Comment: Neither of those filenames match your regular expression pattern: they start with `/myapp` and not `/css`.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the issue @Christopher. I changed my RegEx to `(?!.*\.(?:jpg|png|css|js|json|scss)$).*$` and now it works.

Comment: I am facing a different issue now where my javascript (jQuery api, and other javascript files) are getting loaded twice. Do you know if I am missing something in the rewrite or any other potential cause? I have also asked this as a separate question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528846/javascript-being-loaded-twice-after-enabling-rewrite-through-tomcat-valve)