# Javascript being loaded twice after enabling rewrite through Tomcat valve

Tags: javascript, jquery, tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat-valve

I have a single page application, and I am using the tomcat rewrite valve to forward all the requests other than static resources to my index.html. Following are the contents of my rewrite.config:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?!.*\.(?:jpg|png|css|js|json|scss|map)$).*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```

After getting the rewrite to work, I am seeing that my jQuery library, and other javascript files are loading twice. This is causing the application to break. Could someone point out what could be the potential root cause of this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RewriteRule causes page to reload twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948063/rewriterule-causes-page-to-reload-twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue using this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948063/rewriterule-causes-page-to-reload-twice) The issue was that I was missing some of the file tags. My final rewrite rule looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?!.*\.(?:jpg|png|css|js|json|htm|scss|map|svg|html|favicon\.ico)$).*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```